# Modify all even values with a lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose I have an array like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

How would I modify only the even values using the lens package? I'm looking for something like:

```
filterLens even (+10) $ [1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 12, 3, 14]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Prelude Control.Lens> [1, 2, 3, 4] & each . filtered even %~ (+ 10)
[1, 12, 3, 14]
```

To find functions like this, you can instruct hoogle to search the lens package by putting "+lens" into the search field. In this case: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Blens+filter

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we look at the type we want

```
evens :: Lens' [a] [a]
```

It seems it ought to be a valid lens so long as we don't jiggle with the length of the focused list. It's thus relatively easy to build using getter and settled pairs.

```
evens = lens get set where
  get (a:b:xs) = b : get xs
  get _ = []

  set [] xs = xs
  set xs [] = xs
  set (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:set xs ys
```

But if we pay close attention to the set function we'll see a difficulty with implementing the full filterLens: we abuse the fact that we know the exact structure of the target of the lens. A generic filterLens would need to be able to reconstruct the order to rebuild the total type using only it's piece. For general types and predicates this is impossible or at least difficult to automate.